# Extract Coordinates from KML BatchGeo File with Python

Tags: python, lxml, geocoding, kml, pykml

I've uploaded some addresses to BatchGeo and downloaded the resulting KML file from which I want to extract the coordinates. I managed to prettify the jumbled text file online [here](http://jsbeautifier.org/), but I don't know how to parse it to extract the co-ordinates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>...</name>
            <description>....</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-3.1034345755337,57.144817425039,0</coordinates>
            </Point><address>...</address>
            <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

There seem to be several kml libraries for python but not much in the way of documentation (e.g. [pyKML](http://packages.python.org/pykml/)). Using the tutorial, I have got this far and created an 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object but I'm not sure of its attributes:

```
from pykml import parser

kml_file = "BatchGeo.kml"

with open(kml_file) as f:

    doc = parser.parse(f)

coordinate = doc.Element("coordinates")
print coordinate
```

This gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'Element'
```

So how do I get a list of co-ordinates? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from pykml import parser

root = parser.fromstring(open('BatchGeo.kml', 'r').read())
print root.Document.Placemark.Point.coordinates
```

see [the pykml docs](http://packages.python.org/pykml/tutorial.html#parsing-existing-kml-documents)

hope that helps!

Comment: its returning me only one coordinate not all from kml file.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I didn't have a Point element in the KML, it was a LineString element instead. Furthermore, the text string value of the LineString element had some extra characters in it, so I couldn't just split on comma delimiters, I had to use `re` instead. For eastern north America longs are two-digit negative and lats are two-digit positive, so there was a simple way to separate them according to the negative sign. So to get the list of coordinates:

```
from pykml import parser
import re

kml_file = '/path/to/file.kml'
with open(kml_file) as f:
    doc = parser.parse(f)
root = doc.getroot()
coords = root.Document.Placemark.LineString.coordinates.text
long = re.findall(r'(-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]*)',coords)
lat = re.findall(r'[^-]([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]*)',coords)
print(long,lat)
```