# Inspect and Parse KML with pyKML

Tags: python, kml, pykml

similar to this: [Extract Coordinates from KML BatchGeo File with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712132/extract-coordinates-from-kml-batchgeo-file-with-python)

But I want to know how to inspect the data object, as well as how to iterate it, and parse all the `Placemark` to get the `coordinates`.

The below is the how the KML looks like, and there are multiple `<Placemark>` tags.

**Sample KML data**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
<Document id="...">
  <name>...</name>
  <Snippet></Snippet>
  <Folder id="...">
    <name>...</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>
    <Placemark id="...">
      <name>....</name>
      <Snippet></Snippet>
      <description>...</description>
      <styleUrl>....</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <altitudeMode>...</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates> 103.xxx,1.xxx,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="...">
      ...
    </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Style id="...">
    <IconStyle>
      <Icon><href>...</href></Icon>
      <scale>0.250000</scale>
    </IconStyle>
    <LabelStyle>
      <color>00000000</color>
      <scale>0.000000</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
      <color>ff000000</color>
      <outline>0</outline>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
</Document>
</kml>
```

This is what I have, **extract.py**:

```py
from pykml import parser
from os import path

kml_file = path.join('list.kml')

with open(kml_file) as f:
  doc = parser.parse(f).getroot()

print doc.Document.Folder.Placemark.Point.coordinates
```

This prints the first `coordinates`.

General python question:
How can I inspect `doc`, find out about its type, and print out the values it contains?

Task question:
How do I iterate through all the `Placemark` and get its `coordinates`?

Have tried the following but nothing is printed.

```py
for e in doc.Document.Folder.iter('Placemark'):
   print e
```

Answer (score 15):

I've found the answers.

To parse `Placemark`, this is the code

```py
for e in doc.Document.Folder.Placemark:
  coor = e.Point.coordinates.text.split(',')
```

To find the object type, use `type(object)`.

Not sure why `findall()` and `iter()` didn't work though:

```
doc.Document.Folder.findall('Placemark')

for e in doc.Document.Folder.iter('Placemark'):
```

Both returned empty.

**Update**: Was missing the namespace for `findall` to work.

```
doc.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark')
```